# I want to solve PDEs with NDSolve, but failed

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve `qr(z,t)`,`qi(z,t)`,`v(z,t)` and `T(z,t)` with 4 PDEs. I tried method of  parametricNDsolveValue with parameters of `qr(z)`,`qi(z)`,`v(z)` and `T(z)` with `t` as pars.
But, It does not work, even if I replace `kr=1` and `ki=1`.

When I tried values such as `sol[1][0]`, several messages appear, such as `ParametricNDSolveValue::overdet: ...overdetermined`, `cannot be transposed` and et al. Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

```
 ClearAll["`Global`"] 
 equ=With[{v=v@z,qr=qr@z,qi=qi@z,T=T@t,B=10,n=100,Z=5/2,a0=0.01},
       With[{ve=1.72*Z*n*T^(-3/2)},
        With[{er=1+n*(B-1)/((B-1)^2+ve^2),ei=n*ve/((B-1)^2+ve^2)},
         With[{K1=Integrate[((1-er)Cos[qi*r^2]-ei*Sin[qi*r^2])Exp[-qr*r^2]*r,{r,0,100}],
               K2=Integrate[((1-er)Sin[qi*r^2]+ei*Cos[qi*r^2])Exp[-qr*r^2]*r,{r,0,100}],
               K0=Integrate[ei*Exp[-2*qr*r^2]*r,{r,0,100}],
               kr=((er+(er^2+er^2)^(1/2))/2)^(1/2), 
               ki=((er+(er^2+er^2)^(1/2))/2-er)^(1/2)},
      {D[v,z]==-2*K1*v*qi-K2*v*qr^(-1)(qi^2-qr^2)-4K0*v*qr,
       D[qr,z]==-4*K1*qr*qi-2*K2*(qi^2-qr^2)-4K0*qr^2,
       D[qi,z]==-K1(3 qi^2-qr^2)+K2(-qi^3*qr^(-1) + 3 qi*qr)-4K0*qi*qr,
       D[3/2*n*T/(511*10^3),t]+1/4*D[(kr^2+er)a0^2*v^2*Exp[-2*ki*z],t]==-D[kr*a0^2*v^2*Exp[-2*ki*z],z]-n/2*ve/((B-1)^2+ve^2)*a0^2*v^2*Exp[-2*ki*z]
       }
      ]]]];

  ic={v[0]==1,qr[0]==1,qi[0]==0,T[0]==100};
  sol=ParametricNDSolveValue[{equ,ic},{v,qr,qi,T},{z,0,30},{t}]
  v1[t_,z_]:=sol[t][z][[1]]
```

I appreciate the comments of  Michael E2  and DiSp0sablE_H3r0. The mathematical desciption is that `T`, `qr`, `qi` and `v` depends on `t` and `z`. Especially, when `T(t)` changes in 4th equations, it affects `v`, `qr` and `qi` in the first 3 equations through the parts `er(T)` and `ei(T)`. The initial condition is that `T=100` for all z, and `v=1`, `qr=1` and `qi=0` at `t=0` and `z=0`.  In this way, I used parametricNdsolve, using `t` as pars.

However, I have also used another set of PDEs and NDsolve, but still with error message (a) *NDSolveValue::bcedge: Boundary condition v[0,0]==1 is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain.* and (b) *Set::shape: Lists {vsol,qrsol,qisol,Tsol} and NDSolveValue[<<1>>] are not the same shape.*

```
ClearAll["`Global`"] 
 equ=With[{v=v@@{z,t},qr=qr@@{z,t},qi=qi@@{z,t},T=T@@{z,t},B=10,n=100,Z=5/2,a0=0.01},
       With[{ve=1.72*Z*n*T^(-3/2)},
        With[{er=1+n*(B-1)/((B-1)^2+ve^2),ei=n*ve/((B-1)^2+ve^2)},
         With[{K1=Integrate[((1-er)Cos[qi*r^2]-ei*Sin[qi*r^2])Exp[-qr*r^2]*r,{r,0,100}],
               K2=Integrate[((1-er)Sin[qi*r^2]+ei*Cos[qi*r^2])Exp[-qr*r^2]*r,{r,0,100}],
               K0=Integrate[ei*Exp[-2*qr*r^2]*r,{r,0,100}],
               kr=((er+(er^2+er^2)^(1/2))/2)^(1/2), 
               ki=((er+(er^2+er^2)^(1/2))/2-er)^(1/2)},
      {D[v,z]==-2*K1*v*qi-K2*v*qr^(-1)(qi^2-qr^2)-4K0*v*qr,
       D[qr,z]==-4*K1*qr*qi-2*K2*(qi^2-qr^2)-4K0*qr^2,
       D[qi,z]==-K1(3 qi^2-qr^2)+K2(-qi^3*qr^(-1) + 3 qi*qr)-4K0*qi*qr,
       D[3/2*n*T/(511*10^3),t]+1/4*D[(kr^2+er)a0^2*v^2*Exp[-2*ki*z],t]==-D[kr*a0^2*v^2*Exp[-2*ki*z],z]-n/2*ve/((B-1)^2+ve^2)*a0^2*v^2*Exp[-2*ki*z]
       }
      ]]]];

  ic={v[0,t]==1,qr[0,t]==1,qi[0,t]==0,T[z,0]==100};
  {vsol, qrsol, qisol, Tsol}=NDSolveValue[{equ,ic},{v,qr,qi,T},{z,0,30},{t,0,10}]
```

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory: you have more equations (4) than dependent variables (3). Note that `T[t]` doesn't count as dependent on `z`.  Perhaps you meant to write `T@z` in the first line?

Comment: @MichaelE2 said it already and is also stated in the description of the problem that `t` is just a parameter. Simply change `T = T@t` to `T = T@z` and Mathematica solves it

Comment: You might want to examine the 4th equation, which has $\partial/\partial t$. When applied to any `f@z`, the derivative is zero: Some of the terms in the 4th eq. are annihilated as a result. Is this problem an ODE with parameter $t$ or is it fundamentally a PDE? If you gave a mathematical description of the problem, others might be able to help. Otherwise, they might guess but probably you'll just have to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Thanks! I added the mathematical description and add another set of PDEs, but still not solved.